# using skewness to segment volume

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

my knowledge in statistics is minuscule, sorry. I have a large volume of measured amplitudes. In the absence of a signal, the noise is assumed to have a normal distribution. When a signal is present with higher amplitude than the surrounding noise, the shape of the distribution is more tailed on the positive side. I was thinking of using skewness for detection of signal. But the area of higher amplitude (cells in the volume) is rather small compared to the volume itself. So, we are talking of in magnitude of hundreds of cells from a total of some thousands. If the skewness is zero for a normal distribution, how can I extract those cells in my volume which contribute to the non-zero skewness. If say, my skewness value is 0.5, is there a way to drop all cells and keep only those which raised the skewness value. Perhaps I sound unclear but that just shows how little I understand of the topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem might best be modeled as a mixture model: we have a Gaussian background

B ~ N(0, sigma)

and a signal, about which the poster has not specified a particular model.

If we can assume that the signal also takes the form of one (or possible a mixture of several) Gaussian(s), then Gaussian mixture modelling with the EM algorithm may be a good way to solve it (see Wikipedia).

A good paper in the context of segmentation is this here:

http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~karl/Unified%20segmentation.pdf

If we cannot make such an assumption, I would use a robust regression method to estimate the parameters of the Gaussian noise, where the signal is treated as an outlier, e.g. Least trimmed squares (again see Wikipedia).

The outlier cells can then be found via (Bonferroni-corrected) hypothesis testing, as described e.g. in this paper:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2900857/